# Writing list to file only 10 times, python

Tags: python, file, list

I have a list of lists called `sorted_lists`

I'm using this to write them into a txt file. Now the thing is, this line below prints ALL the lists. I'm trying to figure it out how to print only first n (n = any number), for example first 10 lists.

```
f.write ("\n".join("\t".join (row) for row in sorted_lists)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

`f.write ("\n".join("\t".join (row) for row in sorted_lists[0:N])+"\n")`

where `N` is the number of the first `N` lists you want to print.

`sorted_lists[0:N]` will catch the first `N` lists (counting from 0 to N-1, there are N lists; `list[N]` is excluded). You could also write `sorted_lists[:N]` which implicitly means that it will start from the first item of the list (item 0). They are the same, the latter may be considered more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

`f.write ('\n'.join('\t'.join(row) for row in sorted_lists[:n+1])+'\n')`

where `n` is the number of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplify this code and use the right tools:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv

first10 = islice(sorted_lists, 10)
with open('output.tab', 'wb') as fout:
    tabout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    tabout.writerows(first10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [python slicing features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation).

If you want to look at only the first 10 entires of `sorted_lists`, you could do `sorted_lists[0:10]`.